# react native dynamic setstate with string and dynamic index

Tags: react-native, setstate

react native dynamically generate key1-100 state.  A combination of string and dynamic index. But, how can i do that without sytaz error?

```
this.setstate({ 
     key[index]:1 
})
```

Comment: you should update key[index] outside of setState and just replace key in setSate

Comment: sorry, i dont understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For React Native to detect changes to state and thus re-render your view you must call setState in **immutable** manner. So in your case try the following:

```
//copy state
const newState = {...this.state};
//access property - "key1, key2, etc" whatever index is.
newState['key'+index] = 1;
// set new state
this.setState(newState);
```

Comment: thank you very much. I don't really know it can be written in this way.